# Loading FMOD purely from native code

Tags: android-ndk, fmod

I found an example called nativeactivity in FMOD example folder, but unfortunately it use some java code:

```
package org.fmod.nativeactivity;

public class Example extends android.app.NativeActivity 
{
    static 
    {
        System.loadLibrary("fmodex");
        System.loadLibrary("main");
    }    
}
```

Android.mk looks like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

#
# FMOD Ex Shared Library
# 
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE            := fmodex
LOCAL_SRC_FILES         := libfmodex.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/inc

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

#
# Example Library
#
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE           := main
LOCAL_SRC_FILES        := main.c
LOCAL_LDLIBS           := -llog -landroid
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := fmodex
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android_native_app_glue

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,android/native_app_glue)
```

Is it possible to do without the java part? If so what would I need to change?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know why you want to get rid of these few lines of Java. To the best of my knowledge, this has no effect on the rest of your application.

The reason you need Java is that Android system loader cannot find `libfmodex.so` which is essential to resolve the references in your `libghost.so`. Therefore, load of `libghost.so` fails. Java lets you preload the dependency before your library is loaded.

Unfortunately, NativeActivity itself can only load one library. A [request](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28329) has been posted in April 2012 to improve the situation some time in the future.

Currently, you can switch all your code that works with **fmod** to dynamic linking, or build a third shared library which will load **fmod** and then load the **ghost** library. In this situation, the loader will be able to resolve the references in **ghost** because **fmod** will already be loaded.