# Linking shared fmod library

Tags: android, android-ndk, fmod

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Loading FMOD purely from native code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11427067/loading-fmod-purely-from-native-code)

I'm trying to link fmod library on android ndk project, but I'm getting fatal exception error.

My android.mk looks like this:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

#FMOD Ex Shared Library#########

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE            := fmodex
LOCAL_SRC_FILES         := libfmodex.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/fmod

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)

#lua############################

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := lua
FILE_LIST := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/lua/*.c)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

#libpng########################

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_CFLAGS := 

LOCAL_MODULE    := libpng
FILE_LIST := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/libpng/*.c)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)

#ghost##########################

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := ghost
FILE_LIST := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/ghost/*.cpp)
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog -landroid -lEGL -lGLESv2 -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -ldl -L$(SYSROOT)/usr/lib -lz

# Enable debugging.
APP_OPTIM    := debug

# Support for additional libraries
#LOCAL_CFLAGS := -DANDROID_NDK -Wno-psabi
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/libpng/ $(LOCAL_PATH)/lua/
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := fmodex
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := libpng android_native_app_glue lua

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

$(call import-module,android/native_app_glue)
```

ndk-build command succeeds without any errors, but when I compile, I get following error:

```
10-15 14:25:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(16255): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-15 14:25:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(16255): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.native_activity/android.app.NativeActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to load native library: /data/data/com.example.native_activity/lib/libghost.so
10-15 14:25:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(16255):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1659)
10-15 14:25:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(16255):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1675)
10-15 14:25:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(16255):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:121)
10-15 14:25:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(16255):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:943)
10-15 14:25:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(16255):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-15 14:25:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(16255):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
10-15 14:25:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(16255):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3701)
10-15 14:25:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(16255):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-15 14:25:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(16255):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-15 14:25:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(16255):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
10-15 14:25:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(16255):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:624)
10-15 14:25:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(16255):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-15 14:25:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(16255): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to load native library: /data/data/com.example.native_activity/lib/libghost.so
10-15 14:25:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(16255):    at android.app.NativeActivity.onCreate(NativeActivity.java:199)
10-15 14:25:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(16255):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-15 14:25:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(16255):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1623)
10-15 14:25:49.220: E/AndroidRuntime(16255):    ... 11 more
```

If I remove following lines, the code compiles and runs normally without fmod support.

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE            := fmodex
LOCAL_SRC_FILES         := libfmodex.so
LOCAL_EXPORT_C_INCLUDES := $(LOCAL_PATH)/fmod

include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

and

```
LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := fmodex
```

I tried compiling native activity with fmod example and to my surprise it worked. I even adjusted my file locations to the example but it didn't helped.

Any help would be appreciated.